# how to count the num of ports in docker ps cmd?

Tags: bash, docker

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                           NAMES
f56084659b2a        nginx:alpine        "/docker-entrypoint.…"   35 seconds ago      Up 33 seconds       0.0.0.0:3456->3456/tcp, 0.0.0.0:38080->80/tcp   xenodochial_perlman
```

what is the cmd to actually count num of ports from PORTS column in 1 line?

Comment: `docker port xenodochial_perlman | wc -l`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `inspect` :

```
docker inspect -f "{{len .NetworkSettings.Ports}}" f56084659b2a
```

Answer (score 3):

Ports in itself is a long string, even though it looks like a list. You can see that by using `{{ json . }}` or `{{ json .Ports }}`.

You can work around that by using the split function and then calling len on the resulting slice.

```sh
docker ps --format '{{ len (split .Ports ",") }}'
```

Furthermore, you can still show it in a table, but the column name for that `len` column will be a number. I have not found out yet how to rename columns with the table function. I did ask one time in the slack group, but didn't get an answer to that.

```
docker ps --format 'table {{.Names }}\t{{ len (split .Ports ",") }}'
```